# How to get element from array in Template-Toolkit?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

```
[% a = ['one', 'two', 'four'] %]
[% a.1 %] # it prints two. OK!
```

But when I want this:

```
[% a = ['one', 'two', 'four'] %]
[% n = 1 %]
[% a.n %] # it doesn't work
```

How can I use var n in order to get defined element from array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Template Toolkit has same access to list and hash elements - through dot operator. In your code TT thinks that you want to get value in hash a by key 'n'.
Solution is to use prefix $ before your actual variable in dot operator, in you case:

```
[% a = ['one', 'two', 'four'] %]
[% n = 1 %]
[% a.$n %] # now it works
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to use `[% a.item(n) %]`, which is necessary when you have keys in your hash that are also VMethod names. `.keys`, `.sort`, `.index` are classic examples that can trip you up here.